# Create output-format dependent knitr code

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm looking to have my rmd file run different code depending on whether I'm compiling to html or compiling to pdf.

More specifically, I want to load the latex package `enclose`. If I want to compile to html, I use the command `$$\require{enclose}$$`. If I want to load to pdf, I go into my yaml and use `header-includes: \usepackage{actuarialangle}`.

If I can run different code depending on the compilation method, not only could I load `enclose` if I am compiling to HTML, but I can also define my macro to use the correct function (from `actuarialangle` or `enclose`).

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374492/evaluate-a-chunk-based-on-the-output-format-of-knitr

Comment: That's the idea - but I am thinking outside of chunks. i.e. I want to be able to define a latex / mathjax command differently depending on whether I am loading to pdf or html. This happens outside of a chunk, so this doesn't quite work ( I don't think )