# set chunk options on basis of chunk contents

Tags: r, caching, r-markdown, hook, knitr

I have an R Markdown document. Some R code chunks in this document contain calls to a function, `myFun()`. This function always takes a long time to run. I would therefore like to automatically set any chunks that contain `myFun()` to have `cache = TRUE`. I cannot modify `myFun()`, and the chunks that contain it don't have special identifying features. (For example, they don't have special labels.) Given these constraints, is it possible to automatically set `cache = TRUE` for chunks that contain `myFun()`?

The strategy that I have in mind is to create a chunk hook that searches the text of the chunk for a keyword (`myFun`), and that sets `cache = TRUE` if it finds the keyword. I don't know, though, whether this solution is feasible or whether there's a better way.

I've looked for answers in Yihui Xie's books on knitr and R Markdown, and I've searched issues at the knitr Github site. But I haven't found answers in those places. There are related posts on SO -- for example, [Evaluate a Chunk based on the output format of knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374492/evaluate-a-chunk-based-on-the-output-format-of-knitr). But I haven't found anything that speaks to this problem.

Comment: Why not just cache all chunks?

Comment: Alternatively, why not use `myFun <- memoise::memoise(myFun)` along with `memoise::cache_filesystem( ... )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to agree with @user2554330 that you may want to cache the function `myFun()` instead of code chunks (e.g., with **memoise**).

Anyway, to answer your question: yes, it is possible to set `cache = TRUE` with [an option hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-hooks.html), e.g.,

```r
knitr::opts_hooks$set(cache = function(options) {
  if (any(grepl('myFun(', options$code))) {
    options$cache <- TRUE
  }
  options
})
```

`grepl()` is not an entirely robust way to check if the code chunk contains a call to `myFun()`. If you want a most robust way, you may try `utils::getParseData()`.